# Is a sum of n terms considered O(1) or O(n)?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics

Say I have $n$ numbers in an array and I have to compute the sum of those numbers. Is the complexity considered as $O(1)$ or $O(n)$?

**Clarification**

Say I have 10 constants, I could precompute the total and claim that overall, the complexity is $O(1)$. Yet, if I have 10 assigned variables, I would have to perform 10 additions to compute the total, which implies $O(n)$.

Another way to formulate my question is: Does $O()$ depends on the number of unknowns (i.e. variables) only? How are constants considered?

Comment: If you have ten elements, then that's a constant and considered $O(1)$.  However, if you're given an input to a function, and want to analyze the running time of your algorithm in terms of the input length, then that's $O(n)$, provided that you at least read the entire array (and $n$ is the array length).

Comment: @PålGD: Thanks, that's what I thought too. Don't hesitate to create a solution with your comment and I will approve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have ten elements, then that's a constant and considered $O(1)$.  However, if you're given an input to a function, and want to analyze the running time of your algorithm in terms of the input length, then that's $O(n)$, provided that you at least read the entire array (and $n$ is the array length).

It all has to do with *what you measure your running time in*.  In [parameterized complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity), for instance, we typically measure the complexity in *two* parameters; the length of the input, and an additional *parameter* $\kappa$.  Hence, there you will often see running times like $O(n \cdot 2^\kappa)$.

In your problem, we say $O(n)$ because we sometimes consider "summing integers" as a constant operation.  That's obviously not possible if we allow arbitrarily large integers.  If the max (absolute) integer is $N$, then your algorithm might be $O(n \log N)$.

Comment: Unless practice come into place and we use data paralellism to compute multiple terms at the same time with SIMD instructions :)

Comment: @kuskmen this is probably adifferent model, anyway the speedup is only a constant factor.